Mounting External Intel Raid Device on Linux Failing, No Suitable Superblock and Read Past End
I have a hard-disk from a dead machine that I'm trying to mount on my Linux machine. For reference, I'm using Fedora 39 and mdadm v4.2. First, I tried just mounting it, correctly showing it's a RAID device and cannot be used directly:
$ sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/raid/ --verbose
mount: /mnt/windows10: unknown filesystem type 'isw_raid_member'.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

All as expected. Next, I assembled the RAID device:
$ sudo IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1 mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose

Now, this mounts on md127 and examining it gives the expected results.
$ sudo mdadm --examine --verbose --scan
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=e259cc7b:...
   devices=/dev/sda
ARRAY /dev/md/977KMHHGS container=e259cc7b:... member=0 UUID=ee9548f1:...

However, attempting to get the de5ails gives nothing:
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : imsm
        Raid Level : container
     Total Devices : 1

   Working Devices : 1

     Member Arrays :

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda

Looking at mdstat tells me it's inactive:
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : 
md127 : inactive sda[0](S)
      5201 blocks super external:imsm
   
unused devices: <none>

Attempting to mount it then tells me it has a bad super block and cannot read past the end  of the device:
$ sudo mount -o ro /dev/md/imsm0 /mnt/raid
mount: /mnt/windows10: can't read superblock on /dev/md127.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

dmesg then tells me it's trying to read past the end of the disk:
[18419.063560] GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
[18419.063564] GPT:3907024623 != 3907029167
[18419.063566] GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
[18419.063567] GPT:3907024623 != 3907029167
[18419.063568] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
[18419.063590]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5
[18796.913051] mount: attempt to access beyond end of device
               md127: rw=4096, sector=2, nr_sectors = 2 limit=0
[18796.913060] EXT4-fs (md127): unable to read superblock

Looking back at the logs of assembling the RAID disk it seems the device was busy:
mdadm: /dev/sda is identified as a member of /dev/md/imsm0, slot -1.
mdadm: added /dev/sda to /dev/md/imsm0 as -1
mdadm: Container /dev/md/imsm0 has been assembled with 1 drive
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda5
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda1
mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping
mdadm: no correct container type: /dev/md/imsm0

Is there anything ideal I should do? Is my drive corrupted? I believe this is the only disk from original machine, so it wouldn't require 2 disks or similar. I'm sorry if what I'm asking is relatively rudimentary, and I'd rather not do anything potentially destructive (I'll take it to a data recovery place if there's nothing obviously wrong).
Update 1
Replugging in the device and checking dmesg gives the following result:
[19449.194221] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[19449.207506] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0611, bcdDevice= 0.06
[19449.207513] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
[19449.207515] usb 2-1: Product: Ext. HDD
[19449.207516] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Innostor
[19449.207518] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 20131012
[19449.210360] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[19449.210581] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[19450.215543] scsi host8: scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short (5), using 36
[19450.215549] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Innostor Ext. HDD              PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[19450.216002] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[19450.225777] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[19450.226556] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[19450.226561] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 3b 00 00 00
[19450.227327] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[19450.227331] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[19450.256096] GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
[19450.256099] GPT:3907024623 != 3907029167
[19450.256101] GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
[19450.256101] GPT:3907024623 != 3907029167
[19450.256102] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
[19450.256122]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5
[19450.256351] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk

So it seems that the GPT headers are wrong and this affecting assembling and mounting the disk?
Update 2
Attempting to find the partitions on the assembled drive creates an invalid error.
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/md127 
fdisk: cannot open /dev/md127: Invalid argument

As expected, however, showing the partitions on /dev/sda produces the drives we'd expect:
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device.
Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Ext. HDD        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B98CF9F3-1544-4F34-B8A2-E7B01AE38579

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1026047    1024000  500M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1026048    1288191     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     1288192 3904918338 3903630147  1.8T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  3904919552 3906052095    1132544  553M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  3906054144 3907002367     948224  463M Windows recovery environmen

Update 3
Attempting to mount just /dev/sda3 gives the following error:
$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/windows10 -o ro
mount: /mnt/windows10: fsconfig system call failed: /dev/sda3: Can't lookup blockdev.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call

The dmesg logs seem to be more ominous:
[ 9189.684483] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 9189.684519] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 9189.684534] sd 8:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 c0 58 08 00 00 08 0
[ 9189.684540] I/O error, dev sda, sector 3904919560 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.684650] device offline error, dev sda, sector 3904919560 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.684662] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 1, async page read
[ 9189.684723] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1026056 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.684789] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1026056 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.684798] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 1, async page read
[ 9189.685127] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1288200 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.685187] device offline error, dev sda, sector 3907002104 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.685242] device offline error, dev sda, sector 3907002104 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.685254] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 118495, async page read
[ 9189.685391] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1288200 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 9189.685404] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 8, async page read
[ 9189.685971] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1025784 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.686025] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1025784 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 9189.686035] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 127967, async page read
[ 9189.687413] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 9, async page read
[ 9189.689419] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 10, async page read
[ 9189.689432] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 11, async page read
[ 9189.689438] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 12, async page read
[ 9189.689444] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 13, async page rea

Update 4
Everything looks promising. I tried using dd on the raw drive and there's a lot of plain-text data there so it's clearly not encrypted (it was Windows 10 Home so it couldn't have been via Bitlocker). Running the following:
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda3 of=test bs=512 count=500 skip=7626293

Gave output consisting of this, in plain text (as strings in binary):
/
usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
usr/share/locale/hu/
usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/wget-gnulib.mo
usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
usr/share/locale/id/
usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
usr/share/locale/it/
usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/
usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/wget-gnulib.mo
usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo

So the drive is fine, I'm guessing the offsets for the drive are just off substantially? I'll try to find the actual start of the filesystem.

Are you trying to mount it to get data or to deploy it?   How risk adverse are you?  (It could cause you issues which you might not be able to recover from - but if all else fails, I wonder if you could run testdisk on the raw /dev/sda and get it to find the offset of where the disk actually is [assuming here it was a RAID1], and then adjust things so you can mount it without RAID?

Also, does FDISK show any partitions on md127?

I'm trying to mount it to get data. I'm moderately risk adverse, the important data has been backed up in 2 separate tested locations but there's some data that isn't backed up anywhere. Also, no, fdisk does not show any partitions on md127 (attempting to do fdisk -l /dev/md127 says it' an invalid argument. Updating some info now.

What happens if you just try mount /dev/sda3?    If that does not work, what does it say when you try, and what is the output of lsblk?

To mount the disk you could try something like "sudo mkdir /tmp/raiddisk; sudo mount /dev/sda3 /tmp/raiddisk -o ro"    (Which will mount the disk as read only assuming you have support for the filesystem)

I think at least the fsconfig system call failed: /dev/sda3: Can't lookup blockdev. dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call is more an OS issue than a data or device issue: It doesn't seem to find the blockdev binary. One guess is that this might be related to merging /usr/sbin/ and /sbin/.
